# NFS and KVM. Slow Speed

Tags: linux, virtualization, nfs, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I have a `KVM virtualization` in Debian with 2 guests (Debian and Windows 2008). I want to have a 'mount point' shared that can be accessed by the 3 system (host and 2 guests) at the same time. So the only thing that I found was a `NFS/SMB` network storage. I picked `NFS`

Due to my Ethernet network (10/100), the speed average that I get between accessing/transfering files between the 3 system is always 8~10MB/s.

The point is if is there any chance of get a boost system for sharing files between 3 system (at the same time) without wasting the speed of my `SATA` disks. I mean, without the Ethernet limitation of 10 MB/s

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address aaa.bbb.ccc.xxx (public ip1)
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network aaa.bbb.ccc.0
    broadcast aaa.bbb.ccc.255
    gateway aaa.bbb.ccc.254 (ISP gateway)
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off
```

`eth0` is my physical interface, `br0` the bridge and `vnet+` the VM's interfaces

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled     interfaces
br0     8000.e840f20acc28   no                 eth0
                                               vnet0
                                               vnet1
```

`vnet0` and `vnet1` have two publics different ips. But they also use the same gateway (ISP gateway) of the host

Comment: So you have a single host with two guests and you want to share a filesystem between the host and two guests?  Or do you have a separate file server for all three that's using the FE link?  If it's on the same host are you bridging the three IP's into the same subnet or is the traffic being routed?

Comment: Exactly, it a single host with two guest. But it is not te same subnet, because each one have a public internet IP. It is a OVH server with various failover IP. Anyway, even the two guests like the host are connected to an OpenVPN, where the server host is also the OpenVPN host

Comment: I have just added brctl show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I haven't tried yet, but I think it might work - create a bridge on a dummy interface, and give the VM an interface on that network too. Should eliminate the old NIC from creating bottlenecks in the stack.

Comment: I guess with that I also will have the same issue that now, speed average of 10MB/s. Because they are not **detecting** that are 'the same HDD'. They pass all the 'transfers' via ethernet interfaces

Comment: Yes, NFS is a _NETWORK_ File System after all.

Comment: I already knew thar. I am asking if there any other solution to my scenario

Comment: I have already provided you with the available solutions.

Comment: I already have the `NFS` solution, limited to the `FastEthernet` 10MB/s speed. But I figure out that there is any other possibility to improve that speed, I don't know if without or what, to not wasting my `SATA HDD` speed. They are only virtual machines, the HDD is the same